# Multiple jquery in one page

Tags: jquery

I have a a jquery conflict which I cannot resolve mainly down the the fact I have no idea about it, wonder if anyone could shine a light on it for me? I have 2 scripts running, the first requests jquery.1.3.1 while the 2nd needs jquery.1.7.1, when both exist the first script doesnt work removing 1.7.1 breaks the 2nd script and so on.

Is there a way to have both play nicely on same page, I didnt write either script so not sure how I would update the 1st script to work with 1.7.1?

Kind regards

Comment: You can use `noConflicts()` but you really should upgrade from 1.3 to 1.7

Comment: @ZeeTee that question is for jQuery plugin not for jQuery itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to use:

```
<script src="jquery1.7.1"></script>
<script>
$j17 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="jquery1.3.1"></script>
```

Now you can refer to jQuery 1.7.1 with `$j17` and older version with `$` or `jQuery`.

*Though you should really use the latest version of jQuery.*

Comment: Thanks for positive advice, much appreciated and thank you for your time. It worked a treat, agree really need to upgrade the 1st script but this does the trick on a small site for now. Cheers